# Py4JJavaError: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark via pyspark. I am running the following toy example (in Jupyter Notebook):

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
import random

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")
num_samples = 10000

def inside(p):     
  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
  return x*x + y*y < 1

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()

pi = 4 * count / num_samples
print(pi)

sc.stop()
```

Which runs fine when using num_samples = 100 or similar, but for the given number it returns an error regarding Python Workers:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        [...]
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        [...]
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        [...]
```